# What does "array" in the phrase "liquid cooled array" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following context is from the movie "Mission Impossible Rogue Nation"

This is a link to an excerpt from that movie. The phrase I've got problems with starts at 05:20
Simon Pegg says "All security data is stored in a liquid-cooled **array**"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvNQEyd1Yww&ab_channel=OfficialKRPFilm

These are 3 definitions I found for "**array**" on thefreedictionary that I think might be relevant here:

1. An orderly, often imposing arrangement: an array of royal jewels.
2. An impressively large number, as of persons or objects: an array of heavily armed
3. An arrangement of usually identical devices, often sensors, that function as a unit: an array of solar panels.

Comment: Look up array in computing.

Comment: A liquid-cooled array is a physical structure. Searching for "array in computing" will lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: @Lambie - in computing an 'array' alone (not _of_ some things like hard disks) is a data structure used in coding; like an integer, floating-point number, alphanumeric string [of characters] etc. I don't think the computing term is necessarily helpful. Tech talk in movies is notoriously rubbish.

Comment: It's probably a reference to RAID (redundant **array** of independent disks) storage. Sloppy though, since although ***processors*** might be "liquid cooled", RAID hard drives (or SSD's) wouldn't normally be treated like that. It's just a movie, so technical accuracy isn't important anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  so in this case "array" means "arrangement" right? After googling RAID I can see rows of discs on some kind of metal frame.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Maybe water-cooled drives at home would be overkill, they exist in data centres - [Koolance Hydra-Pak hard drive coolers](https://koolance.com/help-hard-drive-coolers) - with pics of serious-looking racks of drives.

Comment: I still don't know if **"array"** in "redundant array of independent disks" means **"arrangement"**

Comment: [**array**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/array) - *An ordered series or arrangement.*

Comment: Look at the clip. You can "see it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third definition is correct.  As @FumbleFingers mentioned, it's almost certainly a reference to a RAID or RAID-like setup.  While the hard drives in a RAID setup do not have to be arranged in any specific *physical* configuration, they are strictly arranged in a *logical* configuration.  There are several RAID configurations, but one configuration is multiple storage units (hard drives, for example), each one being an exact duplicate of the others.  If one hard drive fails completely, no data is lost.  This makes some sense because if the information is so valuable that it requires the complicated security system surrounding it, it also makes sense that the owner of the information would like to provide redundancy in case a single storage module fails.  This is also a mild example of "technobabble", which is common in science fiction (such as the "flux capacitor" in Back to The Future).

Comment: +1 for "technobabble." Google returns 38 matches for "liquid-cooled array" (*not* 378 as it first indicates) and many of them lead back to Mission Impossible. So it's kind of a thing, but not really.